# Can we say "raise food or donations"?

Tags: word-usage

According to [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/raise), **raise** can mean:

> 8. verb
>      If you raise money for a charity or an institution, you ask people for money which you collect on its behalf.

I am wondering if I can say "**raise food or donations for a charity**"? Or **raise some relief materials**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you *can*, and native speakers certainly *do*:

> [BOY SCOUTS, VOLUNTEERS **RAISE** FOOD DONATIONS FOR HOLIDAYS](http://www.ny1.com/nyc/manhattan/search/news/2017/11/11/boy-scouts--volunteers-raise-food-donations-for-holidays)

Another common expression is to *collect* food, (non-monetary) donations, or relief supplies for some charitable effort, as in the above article:

> Dozens of people are helping regional Ulster and Greene County Food Banks to **collect** food for Thanksgiving and Christmas.

Still, the expression "raise food donations" is not uncommon, at least in headlines:

> Pair of holiday events will **raise food donations** for the less fortunate
>
> Lincoln students **raise food donations** for needy families
>
> Local mayors battle to **raise food donations** for locals in need

However, the text of the article uses "collect" rather than "raise":

> Two mayors with the same goal of providing for families in need will have a friendly competition next week to see who can **collect** the most donations.

Note that it's "raise food *donations*" and not just "raise food", since that means "to grow food plants", or "raise animals for food."